# What does degraded mean in htop?

Tags: debian, systemd

I'm using htop with a custom profile and it says:
`Systemd: degraded (2/298 failed)` where 'degraded' is in scary red bold letters.  How can I find out how to know what's happening or what is degraded?  I'm running Debian 11 non-free at the moment.

Comment: um, no, sorry.  but I did figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I asked in XMPP and somebody told me how it was like this: `systemctl --failed` showed what was failed, then, `systemctl reset-failed` and problem solved!

Comment: Yah that's what the answer to the question I suggested as a dupe says aswell.